# strange and alien memory behavior

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, memory-management

in my project i created a class viewTransistion

```
#import "viewTransition.h"
#import "quiz.h"
#import "mode.h"
#import "result.h"
#import "aboutGame.h"
#import "ViewController.h"


static UIView *cview=nil;
static quiz *quizObj=nil;
static mode *modeObj=nil;
static result *resultObj=nil;
static aboutGame *aboutGameObj=nil;
static ViewController *viewControllerObj=nil;


@implementation viewTransition

+(void) viewsTransitionCurrentView:(id)currentView toNextView:(NSString*)nextViewName
{
    if(nextViewName == @"quiz")
    {
        quizObj = [[quiz alloc]init];
        cview = quizObj.view;

        NSLog(@"quizObj=%d", [quizObj retainCount]);
    }

    if(nextViewName == @"mode")
    {
        modeObj = [[mode alloc]init];
        cview = modeObj.view;

        NSLog(@"modeObj=%d", [modeObj retainCount]);
    }

    if(nextViewName == @"result")
    {
        resultObj = [[result alloc]init];
        cview = resultObj.view;

        NSLog(@"resultObj=%d", [resultObj retainCount]);
    }

    if(nextViewName == @"aboutGame")
    {
        NSLog(@"aboutGameObj=%d",[aboutGameObj retainCount]);

        aboutGameObj = [[aboutGame alloc]init];

        cview = aboutGameObj.view;
    }

    if(nextViewName == @"viewController")
    {
        viewControllerObj = [[ViewController alloc]init];
        cview = viewControllerObj.view;
    }

    [UIView transitionFromView:[currentView view] toView:cview duration:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];

    [currentView release];

    cview = nil;
}

@end
```

its purpose is to perform view transition so i don't have to write code again n again

first i created method and variables of this class as non static...

i checked on device i was getting leaks maybe because i am alloc initing and not releasing objs in if statements

if i release objs in the last i can't perform view transition because on the next view i want to go to is destroyed

......................................

to check i converted this class methods and variables to static so i can check retain counts

the reason why i converted to static...if every time new instance is created of this class i will always get retain count 1 of current instance

now for the first time i execute this it works fine but if you look at aboutGame if block the first execution prints 0 next time if i want to go again on this page the NSLog line becomes zombie???

......................................

in the last line [currentView release] is to remove root view controller ... but i didn't alloc init this i am not the owner so why i should release it.. i saw code in a book to release view controller.

......................................

which is the best way to implement this kind of situation static or non-static

i am using this class method and variable as static and its working fine no leaks no zombies no problem?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations:

- class names should start with a capital letter
- `retainCount` is useless.  Don't call it.
- if you are re-assigning an instance variable (or global), you should release the old value before assignment (this may be the source of your memory leak).
- you are correct;  you shouldn't be releasing `currentView` in that method.

> which is the best way to implement this kind of situation static or
>   non-static

This question doesn't really make sense;  it belies a misunderstanding of how view controllers and memory management work on iOS.

If you can, I would recommend you convert the project to use ARC (automatic reference counting).  That'll mostly take care of the memory management for you (mostly -- you still have to think about it, just not so mechanically).

Next, you'll want to dive back into the "programming with ..." guides related to UIView and UIViewController.

Comment: 'retainCount is useless. Don't call it.' should be in giant bold font :)

Comment: Heh... I'm over it now.   Finally spewed it all on my weblog.  http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to do this

actual thing you do in this function is

[UIView transitionFromView:[currentView view] toView:cview duration:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];

and this is what you want

Comment: ok you are right but i want to know the memory behavior .. so i can understand this memory stuff in more detail .. so complex situation can be handled easily